# What realization to choose for heterogenous container that uses std::variant for data storage?

Tags: c++, oop, c++17

For a program which is a simple rogue-like game, I need a container for storing contents of each room be it enemies, loot, traps, lore-entries etc. Since set of types being held in each room is finite and predetermined I've settled for `std::variant` for data storage. I also will need methods to process the data and here comes the problem. Now due to lack of experience I struggle to choose realization that won't become a burden in long term.

Objective style approach:

```
using myVariant = std::variant<TYpe1, Type2 ... TypeN>;

template <typename V>
class HVector
{
private:
    class HVElem
    {
    private:
        V data;
    public:
        V getData();
    };

    std::vector<HVElem> content;

public:
    void push(V newData);
};

int main()
{
    HVector<myVariant> hVector;
}
```

Functional approach:

```
using myVariant = std::variant<TYpe1, Type2 ... TypeN>;

template <typename V> void push(std::vector<V> hVector, V newData) 
{
    // something
}

int main()
{
    std::vector hVector<myVariant>;
}
```

Questions:

1. Which of the two approaches is better? I have a strong feeling that simply using `std::vector<std::variant<>>` with some template functions is enough in this case. Is using objective style even requiered here?
2. How can I prevent the program from creating a container that holds anything other than `std::variant<>`? Is there a way to simply list types in type aliases so that I could simply write `std::vector<std::variant<myTypes>>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which of the two approaches is better?

Neither, see option 3 below.

> How can I prevent the program from creating a container that holds anything other than std::variant<>?

```
using myVariant = std::variant<TYpe1, Type2 ... TypeN>;
using myVector = std::vector<myVariant>;
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about storing methods? Should I just write standalone functions or encapsulate functions with `myVector` inside a class?

Comment: Nothing. It's just tricky to access and process data inside `std::variant` especially when held types are being classes instead of base types like `int` or `float`.